When I press Ctrl + S a beep sound is heard
I'm developing a Windows Forms application in C#. I have implemented a feature to save changes using the Ctrl + S key combination. However, I encounter an unwanted beep sound every time I press these keys. I would like to know how to suppress this sound.
Below is the code for my form and the key handling logic:
public partial class fQuanLyNCKH : Form
{
    public fQuanLyNCKH()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadProjectsData();
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyDown += Form_KeyDown;
        btnLuu.Click += (s, e) => SaveChanges();
    }

    private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true; // This is supposed to prevent the beep
            SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

What I've Tried
I've implemented the e.SuppressKeyPress = true; to suppress the beep sound, but it still occurs. I’ve also checked other controls to ensure they aren't conflicting with the key event.
Question
How can I prevent the beep sound from occurring when I use the Ctrl + S key combination in my Windows Forms application?

Could you try also doing e.Handled = true; in the Form_KeyDown handler?

@500-InternalServerError Redundant, the SuppressKeyPress property setter sets the e.Handled property as well.

Maybe something in the SaveChanges method call is delaying processing the msg. Such as showing a modal dialog. Set the property and replace SaveChanges with BeginInvoke(new Action(() => SaveChanges())); and see how it goes.

It's (maybe) complaining about the "context". The "focus" is sitting somewhere so that it can't figure out that your key combination is supposed to be "valid". Maybe the focus is on the same button that "also" does a save.

If you have a menu in your application, you should just set the Save menu item's text to &Save (I.e. put an ampersand before the accelerator key). IIRC, it should then handle this automatically and you won't have to handle key press events yourself.

try by adding 'e.Handled=true;' the following at Form_KeyDown event
private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            e.Handled=true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            SaveChanges();
        }
    }

